# equal operator not working on concatenated columns of a view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

VIEW Definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW AS SELECT a.column1||'/'||a.column2 as c1,
       b.column1 as c2,
       .
       .
       From table1 a join table2 b on 
       (a.id=b.id)
       join more tables (8 more tables)
```

My Query:

```
SELECT * from MY_VIEW WHERE c1 = '1234567/1';
```

I have above View and query that I am using in Oracle. For some reason the query does not return data though there is data present in MY_VIEW for few rows.

I checked if there is any problem with the data by using length, trim, to_char functions, but I did not see any problems.

If I run below query directly on table1 for the same data I get values.

```
select a.column1||'/'||a.column2 
from table1 
where a.column1||'/'||a.column2 = '1234567/1'
```

Have any one of you ever faced this before? I went through each step of creating view and writing my query over and over again but I did not find anything different. The fact that the query works for some data makes me believe that something should be wrong with the data but the tables being used are not modified manually.

I tried with the like operator as below

```
select * from my_view where c1 like '1234567/1%'
```

This works as expected. But the `length()` function does not give me a different number than what I can see.

Can anyone let me know if there is a way that I can use to find if any special characters are present data?

**Update 1:**

```
select count(1) from my_view;
```

Above query gives me 13.

```
select * from my_view where rownum < 15;
```

Above query does not give any rows.

```
select * from my_view where rownum < 100;
```

Above query returns all the 13 rows in the view.

Comment: How can the string literal `data` match something with a forward slash in it?  I think the problem is with your data, or at least your understanding of the data you have.

Comment: `a.column1||'/'||a.column2` will never equal 'data' since the values of two fields are concatenated with '/' beeing in the middle.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The actual data is something like '1234567/1'

Comment: This does sound weird. In most questions along the lines of *"why is my database is my database doing something weird?"* it turns out the database wasn't doing something weird and the questioner misunderstood what was actually occurring. Probably the data is different from what you think it is. If you want us to help you must post a reproducible test case. That would comprise two tables, a view and sample data which demonstrates the effect you assert.

Comment: @APC i do get it. But I am not sure if I can reproduce this. I have updated the question with more information. I'll try to reproduce this and see with different tables.

Comment: Anything which cannot be reproduced does not exist.

Comment: Why do you concatenate those columns at all? It will be much better to compare the values of each column individually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I assumed that the problem might be with the concatenation and then made them into two different columns. Even then the where clause on column1 is not working on view with =. It works with like as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Continuing to post "weird" stuff doesn't progress us. Please post **a reproducible test case**.

Comment: FYI, with my own example, this works for me.  Simplify your example to a reproducable example for anyone to recreate, DLL and data.  I did a simple view and the following works like a charm.  select * from   v1 where  c3 = '1234567/1';

Comment: @unleashed This worked me for past one month. It started happening only from friday. I am trying to replicate the issue with different set of tables and data. I'll update the question once I am able to replicate the issue.

Comment: @SachinKumar For your update, what does select rownum, my_view.* from  my_view; return?  It may not be what you are expecting.

Comment: @unleashed: I have figured out the root cause, but unsure on how views work. The reason was that there was a view being used in the join and the where clause at the end of my query was somehow impacting the view and the data in the view was getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

> "Can anyone let me know if there is a way that I can use to find if any special characters are present data?"

You can use the built-in function `dump()`. This gives the datatype and length of the passed value, and internal representation of it (as same ASCII values).

```
select dump('2300/1') as your_case
from dual
/
```

returns

```
Typ=96 Len=6: 50,51,48,48,47,49
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8be31/1).

Comment: `Typ=1 Len=9 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: 1,2,8,5,9,6,1,/,1 1285961/1`. Do you see anything that is non standard in this. I am not aware of these details and their use in a database.

Comment: I would expect the result to be the ASCII values i.e. `49,50,56,53,57,54,49,47,49`.